# pasar consulta sql a query builder

Tags: laravel, sql-server

Necesitaría que me ayuden a pasar esta consulta a query builder,
desde ya muchas gracias!

Antes les comento resulta que en una vista tengo que devolver la cantidad de contenidos agrupado por categorías y que tenga el tipo de  recurso x , actualmente me devuelve la cantidad de los contenidos por categoría sin discriminar el tipo de recurso .
En el motor de la base de datos esta consulta me devuelve lo deseado.

```
select cat.id, 
       cat.description, 
       count(distinct c.id) as,
       cantidad_contenidos 
from category cat
left join contents c on c.category_id = cat.id
where cat.deleted_at is null 
    and c.deleted_at is null 
    and exists (select 1 
                from content_tipo_recursos ctr 
                where ctr.tipo_recurso_id = 3 
                    and ctr.content_id = c.id)
group by cat.id, cat.description
```

Comment: Tienes los modelos y relaciones creadas?

Answer (score 1):

Espero esto te ayude bro, no lo he probado, solo agrega los campos que necesitas en el select().

```
DB::table('category')
        ->leftjoin('contents', 'category.id', '=', 'content.id') 
        ->select('category.*', DB::raw('count(content.id)'))
        ->where('category.deleted_at', 'is', null)
        ->where('content.deleted_at', 'is', null) 
         ->whereExists(function($query) {
               $query->select(DB::raw(1)) 
                  ->from('content_tipo_recursos') 
                  ->where('tipo_recurso_id', '=', 3) 
                  ->where('content_tipo_recursos.content_id', '=',            
  'content.content_id');    
}) 
->groupBy('category.id', 'category.description')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Pues iría dentro del select, de ahí porque le puse que me faltaron los campos y que se lo agregara amigo pero si hay dudas pues aquí un ejemplo 
  select('count(campo)) saludos

Comment: Según la documentación si funciona, pero pues sería de probar como dije no lo he probado saludos.

Comment: No hay problema lo agregare en la respuesta pero creo que no se leyó mi comentario arriba del Código

Comment: Tienes razón amigo, listo lo agregue DB::raw('count(campo)')

Comment: Gracias! , me sigue devolviendo el mismo resultado , no me filtra , es extraño .